# Get pixel value of each pixel of a gray-scale or black-white image?

Tags: java, image, histogram, pixel

can any one suggest me the method to get actual pixel value of each pixel of a gray scale image?

i used this code to get pixel. But it just gives me red value of an pixel? I don't know that black-white or Gray Scale image contains RGB pixels or not, So please tell me that, the method i used is right or wrong? And also when i plotted histogram for my image it was exactly opposite to the imajeJ histogram for same image. So i guess my method to grab pixel of Gray Scale image is somewhere wrong

So If it is wrong what is the right way to get pixel. 
here is my code

```
 PlanarImage image = JAI.create("fileload", "C:\\16bit images\\alpXray.tiff");
 BufferedImage bi = image.getAsBufferedImage();
  int[] bins = new int[256];
 int b=0;
for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {

         for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {

             int p= bi.getRaster().getSample(x, y,b); // (1)  b=0 for red (2)b=1 for green(3) b=2 for bule

           p=p/256;

           bins[p]++;  
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every channel of a RGB image is in gray scale. in fact if you visualize a single channel (GIMP, photoshop) you see only gray shades.

usually to convert a  rgb image to gray you take the three values of every channel and do a arithmetic mean.
or simply you take a single channel.
tell me if i misunderstood the question..

EDIT: 
ok. if you have 3-channel gray scaled image probably you have 3 channel with same value on each channel. so simply take the value of single channel for each pixel.
if you  have only one channel (of 16bit) take that pixel.